# Slick nextArrow and prevArrow button customize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to change the ***nextArrow and prevArrow*** of the [**SLICK ( SLIDER SYNCING )**](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to the image of the ***next and prev image item***?

> **LIKE THIS SCREENSHOT**

[image: the next and prev button shoud be like this]

> **DEFAULT SLICK ARROW**

```
prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev aria-label="Previous" tabindex="0" role="button">previous</button>',
nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="Next" tabindex="0" role="button">next</button>',
```

Comment: They don't offer that design. You can easily create it on javascript. :)

Comment: @LaraBelle so you mean I will create on my own without using slick?

Comment: You can create it without slick or you modify slick. Or try to find another library.